# How to bypass SDL2's built-in main function on ios

Tags: ios, sdl

When using SDL2 on ios, SDL renames the main() function written by me to SDL_main, or I write a SDL_main function directly. And then SDL uses its own [main function](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/1b24bfa/src/video/uikit/SDL_uikitappdelegate.m#L45), as the real entry point. But in my use case I would like to retain control on the real entry point, i.e. the program starts from my main function instead of SDL's. Is there a config to disable SDL mangling my main function? Furthermore, after re-gaining control on the entry point, what is the necessary steps to prepare the necessary stuff for SDL to run correctly?

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady remarks section.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more than that. Since SDL's entry point on ios involve creaing an application + a view, registering events and such. So I would also like to know what is the correct way to replicate those stuff if I bypassed SDL's main function.

Comment: Okay, and you've already found main function SDL uses, so you see what you need to do. Also there is no conditions around `main` here - hence no compilation flags can disable it, only code modification. What exactly seems to be a problem here? Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: The reason is simple, I need to embed SDL in an existing app, that means I have to have control on how SDL starts.

Comment: Then I suppose you'll have to modify SDL source code, probably extending it with event feeding at least. It may be much simplier to modify app to use SDL's main instead.